# Is it possible to describe array of objects in one line without using braces?

Tags: coffeescript

---

I am learning CoffeeScript and got a question:

> Is it possible to describe array of objects in one line?

So, I can do it in multiple lines without braces:

```coffee
arr = [
        name: "name",
        age: 123
    ,
        name: "anothername",
        age: 321

]
```

But, is it possible to do this in one line?

Comment: But why you wanna do this ?

Comment: [Is Coffeescript dead?](https://www.quora.com/Is-CoffeeScript-dead)

Comment: @CodeManiac because it is a function parameter and i want it to be oneline.
I do not want to make individual variable.